# Tumbler account lost

Tags: tumblr, password-recovery

Last night, I was deleting cookies on my daughter's mac and (maybe coincidentally) now she can't access her Tumblr account.  She can only view it as a follower.  Any ideas on how to reinstate her to her blog?

Answer (score 3):

Since you have to use an email address to sign up you can use Tumblr's [Forgot Password](https://www.tumblr.com/forgot_password) form to go through resetting the password.